# Having iframe element swipe into the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to achieve this:

When a user clicks a button, an iframe element will swipe into the screen from the left, covering half the screen over 1 second. When the user clicks anywhere else on the screen (not in the iframe) the iframe swipes back out.

I am new to HTML and JavaScript so I'm hoping someone can provide me with details on how to implement this.

My current idea is this:
1. Having the iframe position-left initialized to some point -1000px so it is out of the screen.
2. When the user presses the button, use a CSS transition to move the position-left to 0px

The problems I have is:
1. How to make the iframe disappear when user clicks anywhere else on the screen
2. What if I wanted to iframe to swipe from the right?

Is my concept correct? I'm new to the details in coding HTML so although I know the concept, I'm having trouble converting it to code.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Also I would like to implement some cool features, but they are not essential: the iframe appears not when user click a button but swipes with his mouse/finger anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I've interpreted your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/5TXvF/

To setup the box I've used your idea of having the box offset to the left:

```
<a href="#" class="flying-activate">Fly It Out</a>

<div id="flying-box">
    <!-- Content or iFrame -->
    <iframe src="http://www.google.ca" />
</div>
```

In this case you don't necessarily need to use an iframe, the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#flying-box {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    left: -50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#flying-box iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm assuming from your description that you want to cover half the page so it's important to define your HTML and BODY with height: 100% so your DIV can also extend to the height of the page.

The jQuery to accompany this is as is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var flying_on = false;

    $('a.flying-activate').click(function(e) {
        $('#flying-box').animate({left: 0}, 1000, function() {
            flying_on = true;
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('body').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id != 'flying-box') {
            $('#flying-box').animate({left: '-50%'}, 1000, function() {
                flying_on = false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The flying_on variable is to keep track of that state. The first function is to activate the DIV sliding in over the span of 1 second. To have the DIV close clicking anywhere else I'm listening for a click on the body, as long as the ID where the user click is not where the flying box is then it'll close.